# In React, why does adding state that is a number to prop that is a number results in string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I do the following:

```
this.setState( { skip: this.state.skip + this.props.PageSize } );
```

the result is a string, (e.g. "0555" when it tries to add 5 every click)

During debugging, it shows this.state.skip as a number, but this.props.PageSize as a string. However, the prop is defined as a number:

```
export interface IMyProps{
  Description: string;
  Context: WebPartContext;
  Environment: string;
  PageSize: number;
}
```

Do I always have to parse React props? Seems odd.

Edit: trying to do the following:

```
parseInt(this.props.Pagesize)
```

fails because, well obviously, you can't parse a number to an int, only a string.

Comment: Apparently, you're passing a string as the prop. Could you show us where you're using this component?

Comment: Looking at propTypes it looks like `pageSize` should be a number but you are getting string. Try to find the place where a string value is getting updated in `PageSize` variable. This isn't react fault and looks more of a logic issue

Comment: I already had this kind of issue, I think it was something like `<MyComponent page="1">` instead of `<MyComponent page={1}>`

Comment: Thanks, Milind. The prop was being set by another object's prop that got its value from a TextBox. While the parent prop was defined as a number, it apparently didn't matter. I've updated the parent to set the prop with a parseInt of the parent property when set and a default value when not, and it's working. Thanks! If you want to make your comment an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @RandySlavey Have a look at my answer, I suggested few more enhancement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the details you provided, it looks like a logic issue but you can change your code like below to fix this issue

```js
const { PageSize } = this.props;
this.setState(prevState => ({ skip: prevState.skip + parseInt(`${PageSize}`) }));
```

**prevState.skip**

We should use function inside `setState` when new state should be updated based on the current state.

**parseInt(`${PageSize}`)**

This make sure that you are having string value and then parse it to Integer.

*This won't be required if you make sure that number is passed instead of string*

Answer (score 1):

As commented by [patrick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479654/patrick-ferreira):

Anything you pass inside the quote will be string.

```
myprop="1" // 1 is string here
myprop={1} // 1 is number here
```

So, you have to use curly brace to use number or variable but not quote.

Hint: You may also use the following to fix your issue:

```
this.setState( { skip: this.state.skip + +this.props.PageSize } );
```